# Template function returning a const template type

Tags: c++, templates, pointers, constants

Why doesn't the following produce a compiler error?

```
template<typename T>
const T testFunc()
{
    return T();
}

float* ptr = testFunc<float*>(); // ptr is not const - should be a compiler error!
```

In this example, testFunc() should be returning a constant float*, so shouldn't there be a compiler error when I try to assign it to a non-const float* ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are wrong on your expectations, the returned *pointer* will be const, not the object pointed. The specialization is equivalent to:

```
float * const testFunc<float*>();
```

Rather than:

```
float const * testFunc<float*>();
```

In your example, the code at the call side is *copying* from a const pointer to a non-const pointer, which is fine.

Comment: Then how do I make the templated function return a constant pointer?

Comment: @jlanisdev: It depends, the simplest thing that you can consider is rewriting the template as: `template <typename T> T const * testFunc();`. The call site would pass `float`: `float const * ptr = testFunc<float>();`. Note, `const T*` and `T const *` are equivalent, but the later is *more consistent* to parse for humans --i.e. if you always add `const` to the right, it becomes obvious in the question that the original template did not return a pointer to const: `template <typename T> T const testFunc()` with `T == float*` ==> `float* const testFunc()`

Comment: However, in the original example, I did not add const to the right. I added it to the left, so if you simply replace "T" with "float*" you get: "const float*". I sort of understand what you are trying to say, but to me it just makes more sense how I interpreted it than what the compiler is actually doing.

Comment: @jlanisdev: No, that is where you are wrong. The `const` is applied to `T`, `const T` and `T const` are exact equivalents. In the comment I was recommending that *you* write the `const` to the right, as that makes things less confusing. `const T` and `T const` are the same, and with `T == float*` they mean `float* const`. My suggestion is that, if you get used to writing the `const` to the right, then the parsing that the compiler does of the expression is closer to *textual substitution* and is thus easier for *you* to understand (note neither the `T` nor a `typedef` are textual substitution)

Comment: That seems so incredibly unintuitive. I suppose I'll have to keep this in mind in the future (I think I've always assumed textual substitution, which is my problem).

Comment: @jlanisdev: while many people consider type substitution as a textual substitution it is not. The rules are actually simpler than you think, and doing otherwise would be just as unintuitive. Consider for example that you instantiated the template with `int**`, what should be `const`? `const int **`, `int * const *`, int ** const`? If you *read* the type aloud, the function returns a constant `T`, with `T` being  a  `float` pointer, the function returns a constant `float` pointer (not a *pointer to constant `float`*)

Comment: Ah, I can see how that makes more sense now. I'll try to keep const to the right from now on. :)